# SQLAchemy New Uppercase Code field type with TypeDecorator

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Happy New Year. Wish you all the best in 2016.

I want to create a new column type which automatically converts to uppercase when assigned. So far I have the following code:

```
class CodeColumn(db.TypeDecorator):
    impl = db.String

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        return value.upper()

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        return value.upper()


class Item(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'item'
    code = db.Column(CodeColumn(30), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
```

It seems to work but the value is converted to uppercase only on db.session.commit():

```
./manage.py shell
>>> i = Item()
>>> i.code = 'apple200'
>>> i.code
'apple200'
>>> i.name = 'Apples 200'
>>> db.session.add(i)
>>> db.session.flush()
>>> i.code
'apple200'
>>> db.session.commit()
>>> i.code
'APPLE200'
>>>
```

Would it be possible to amend the code without adding implementation, like property setter, to the individual columns but rather to the TypeDecorator so that values of such fields are automatically converted to uppercase when first assigned?

I know that I can achieve the effect with events or property setter, but I would like to have a custom column type to avoid setting those events and setters in multiple places.

Thanks